# React Hook Form errors in aria-live

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-hook-form

I have tried to use aria-live attribute (one container) on the form with error list (Screen reader always read all changes, I need to read only new error) and this doesn't work for me, what's wrong?

```
const {
    control,
    register,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
} = useFormContext()

return <div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="false">
    {Object.values(errors)?.map((error, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>{error?.message}</div>
    })}
 </div>
```

Comment: What happens if you move your aria tags into the div being mapped instead of the container?

Comment: @Micky, it (VoiceOver) can read old aria-live blocks twice

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to help. I think what you're trying to accomplish might be outlined in this article https://almerosteyn.com/2017/09/aria-live-regions-in-react

Comment: Are you attempting to render the entire live region with all the content? For a live region to announce anything, it has to be present in the DOM at time of page load with no content. You then add content to the live region through scripting, and assistive technology will announce it.

Comment: @Josh, initially it's in the DOM without any content